# Forward client port to my computer

Tags: 16.04, port-forwarding

I need to send packets through a server port number 38xxx and then receive packets using UDP protocol from a client port number 48xxx. How can I implement this port forwarding in order to receive the packets successfully ? 
I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

In my firewall I do a couple of things to create a proxy between my main computer and my Intranet computers:

In the FORWARD queue, I have something like this:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED \
                            -m tcp ! -s 10.10.0.1 -d 10.10.1.2 ! --syn -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED \
                            -m udp ! -s 10.10.0.1 -d 10.10.1.2 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any \
                            ! -s 10.10.0.1 -d 10.10.1.2 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -p tcp -m tcp -s 10.10.0.1 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -p udp -m udp -s 10.10.0.1 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any \
                            -s 10.10.0.1 -j ACCEPT
```

I've noticed that having ICMP can help hence that line. If you don't want to support TCP, obviously don't add that one.

My `FORWARD` definitions don't include any port specification which means all packets are forwarded, whatever the port. Try to add the source and destination port command like:

```
--sport 38000
--dport 43000
```

If I'm correct, you have to look at the multiport capability to include a range of ports (something like this: `-m multiport --dport 38000-38999`, it may be a colon (`:`) and not a dash (`-`) between the start and end port specification [so `38000:38999`].)

Then in the NAT filter, I add POSTROUTING commands as follow:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -s 10.10.1.2  -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.0.1
```

The IP address in `--to-source ...` has to be on the same Ethernet card but it does not need to be the same IP address. This is practical if you have a static IP address. In my case I actually have `eth0` with my static IP address and `eth0:1` with `10.10.0.1` and it works!